# Is the Nintendo Pro Controller better than Joy Con?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch

I bought Switch last year. And this is my first Nintendo Console. I recently bought Tears of the Kingdom. I feel so good playing the game. However, I am wondering if the Pro Controller will make the gameplay experience better.

So,

Should I buy the Pro Controller to improve my gameplay experience ?

Comment: The second part may lead to speculations, so I'm not gonna answer that. How are you playing with the Joy Con? Just one? Or with the "dog" controller?

Comment: Speaking from experience, the Switch Pro Controller is completely worth it. However, I'm not going to post as an answer as this question borderline subjective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the Pro Controller is better depends on your needs.

If you intend to take your Switch with you and play wherever you go, the Joy Cons are going to be more convenient, as they take up less space, and can be charged via the Switch itself. They also allow you to play without a flat surface for the Switch to rest on, by attaching the Joy Cons to the Switch and playing while holding the console.

On the other hand, the Pro Controller is larger and more comfortable to use. Its shape is more ergonomic, and its buttons and sticks are placed in a more convenient location.

Performance-wise, there is no big difference between the two, although the Pro Controller does offer a larger battery, allowing for longer gaming sessions without having to recharge ([40 hours](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22498/%7E/nintendo-switch-pro-controller-faq) vs [20 hours for Joy Cons](https://www.nintendo.com/us/switch/tech-specs/#joycon-section)). In addition, the Pro Controller is said to be less susceptible to drifting, compared to the Joy Cons.

Feature-wise, the Joy Cons are slightly superior. They can be shared with another player, allowing for 2 people to play together with only one set of Joy Cons, and feature an IR depth sensor. They also provide you with 2 sets of accelerometer and gyroscope instead of just 1 for the Pro Controller. None of which are relevant for Tears of the Kingdom, however. The game neither has a multiplayer mode, nor does it make use of the IR depth sensor in any way (in fact, [very few games do](https://www.destructoid.com/right-switch-joy-con-has-an-ir-sensor-heres-what-uses-it/)). It also only polls accelerometer and gyroscope data from one of the Joy Cons (the right one, if I'm not mistaken), not both.

One non-obvious advantage the Joy Cons may have over the Pro Controller, is that you don't have to hold them right in front of you, which allows for a more relaxed posture and might be less tiring for your arms over time. How much of an advantage that is depends on the individual, however. As an example of that, I tend to play with both arms resting on my armchair's armrests. This is not something I can do with a Pro Controller.

To summarize:

**Joy-Cons**: are more convenient and offer a few additional features (that TotK doesn't use and few games do).

**Pro Controller**: is generally more comfortable to hold and use, and has a higher battery life.

Whether the Pro Controller is worth it, that will depend on your use case.

PS: As there is no concrete information about the Switch 2 (just rumors), it's impossible to say if you should buy the Pro Controller now (should you choose to do so) or wait for the next console.

Comment: Can I use the Pro Controller when the Joy Cons are attached to the Switch ?

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever compatible controller when Joy Cons are not in use